# Imported angular module doesn't work the first time a route is visited, but it works in the subsequent visits

Tags: css, angular, typescript, sass

I have a simple Loader Module hosted in a private npm repository. This module only intercepts http calls and displays a css loader. The code is simple: it has a public api that exports the module and a component. The module has an http interceptor that calls a service which sets a variable `isLoading`.

The component code is split into three files, as usual (ts, html and scss).

loader.component.ts

```js
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { LoaderService } from '../service/loader.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'loader',
  templateUrl: './loader.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./loader.component.scss']
})
export class LoaderComponent implements OnInit {

  public isLoading: boolean;

  constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) { }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.loaderService.isLoading.subscribe(status => this.isLoading = status);
  }
}
```

loader.component.html

```html
<div *ngIf="isLoading" class="overlay">
  <div class="loader center-block"></div>
  <p class="wait">
    <strong>Wait...&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong>
  </p>
</div>
```

The `loader.component.scss` file defines the `loader`, `overlay` and `wait` css classes (not shown for brevity).

The interceptor code is here:

```js
@Injectable()
export class LoaderInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private loaderService: LoaderService) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<unknown>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    this.loaderService.show();
    return next.handle(request).pipe(finalize(() => this.loaderService.hide()));
  }
}
```

And finally, the service code:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoaderService {
  public isLoading: Subject<boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this.isLoading = new Subject<boolean>();
  }

    show() {
        this.isLoading.next(true);
    }
    hide() {
        this.isLoading.next(false);
    }
}
```

This module is imported at the `app.module.ts` of an application and declared in the imports array of the decorator.

The application has some routes with [lazy load feature modules](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#lazy-loading-feature-modules).

The loader module is used at the `app.component.html` file, as follows:

```html
<loader></loader>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

The problem: the loader does not work the first time we visit a route, but it works if we click the previous button at the browser or we click to go back to homepage or any other way I tested visiting a route twice or more. Otherwise, it doesn't work.

I tried to find similar questions, I tried to see the order of css imports, I also tried to analise the loader module, the import order, but no clue about what is happening.